# Tutorial para desenvolver app Andorid com Parse

Tags: android, parse

Já procurei em tudo que é canto e não achei, alguém sabe indicar algum tutorial de outro local que não seja do site [parse.com](http://parse.com)?

Comment: No google, tente retirar o parse.com dos resultados, com `- parse.com` e refinar a pesquisa para apenas os sites brasileiros (ou não, se dominar o inglês). lgo assim: https://www.google.com.br/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#lr=lang_pt&tbs=lr:lang_1pt&q=tutorial+android+parse+-+parse.com

Comment: @gustavox. Muito Obrigado pela dica, mas já pesquisei de tudo e não acho nada que ajude, tudo meio que genérico, obrigado mesmo assim.

Comment: Editei o comentário porque imaginei mesmo que ia parecer que tava só indicando o goolge pura e simplesmente ^^. Pelo link que coloquei acima vc chega aqui por exemplo: http://www.fellyph.com.br/blog/tutoriais/parse/ ou http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/br/library/j-parse/. Espero que seja útil.

Comment: Editei sua pergunta tentando aumentar as chances dela não ser fechada (poderá ser considerada muito ampla ou fora de escopo). Dá uma olhada se ainda espelha o que vc quer.

Comment: Muito boa a edição e aconselho o link que você passou para outras pessoas, infelizmente na internet tem pouca coisa a respeito do parse.com, que por sinal é uma tecnologia muito boa. Obrigado e continuarei procurando sempre algo mais relacionado ao parse.com. Já votei porque sei que poucas pessoas conversam sobre o assunto. Se você utiliza o parse.com da uma olhada no link do meu post: [http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/60768/mudar-cor-do-background-da-textview]

Comment: Ok, boa sorte, e se encontrar algo relevante não se esqueça de colocar aqui. Abraços.

Comment: Então, eu não conheço `parse`, mas fiz uma pequena edição e dei +1 na sua pergunta, pra ajudar a destacá-la na página inicial. Espero que consiga resolver. Pelo que tenho visto, é raro a galera aqui não resolver este tipo de pergunta que vc fez. Se não encontrar logo, vc também pode oferecer uma recompensa. Veja aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties

Comment: É eu vi isso, também procurei no GUJ e não encontrei resposta ainda, espero que consiga algo, pois também tentarei ajudar caso consiga desenvolver meu app. Obrigado.